# Kennzeichnung aspirierter Plosive (z.b. TH in Theater, Thron usw.)

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, history

Als [Plosive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plosiv) bezeichnet man jene Konsonanten, bei denen der Laut dadurch gebildet wird, dass der Luftstrom für einen kurzen Moment unterbrochen wird. Das anschließende geräuschvolle Entweichen der angestauten Luft erzeugt dann den Laut, der entfernt an eine Explosion erinnert. Daher rührt auch der Name.

Im Deutschen sind das die Lenis-Laute b, d und g sowie die Fortis-Laute p, t und k.

Nach meinem Wissensstand sind im Deutschen alle drei Fortis-Plossive immer aspiriert, das heißt, es ist danach immer ein kurzes Atemgeräusch zu hören, das, wenn es allein artikuliert wird, durch den Buchstaben h wiedergegeben wird. Daher lautet die korrekte Notation der genannten Laute in der Lautschrift eigentlich auch: pʰ, tʰ und kʰ (das keine hochgestellte h symbolisiert den aspirierten Charakter des Plosiv-Lauts).

Das ist z.B. in Romanischen Sprachen nicht so. Das »ti« im italienischen »ti amo« (»ich liebe dich«) hat ein t das nicht aspiriert wird. Es korrekt auszusprechen ist ein Problem für Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache, weil sie nie gelernt haben, t unaspiriert auszusprechen. Diese Aspiration der Laute p, t und k ist Deutschsprechern so sehr in Fleisch und Blut übergegangen, dass ihnen diese Art diese Konsonanten auszusprechen gar nicht bewusst ist.

In der Vergangenheit war es aber so, dass an den Buchstaben t sehr oft ein h angefügt war, um eben diese Aspiration auch in der Schriftform wiederzugeben:

vor 1876:

- Armuth = Armut
- Gluth = Glut
- Noth = Not
- Unterthan = Untertan

vor 1901:

- Thal = Tal
- Thür = Tür
- Thor = Tor
- Thee = Tee

Warum das beim p nicht gemacht wurde ist mir klar, denn der Digraph ph war schon mit einem anderen Laut (nämlich f) belegt. Aber gibt es auch Beispiele für »kh«? Wenn nein: Warum nicht? Warum wurde nur das t entsprechend gekennzeichnet?

Comment: Would /t/ and /p/ really be aspirated in all environments ?  Mutter /mutʰɐ/, Mut /mu:tʰ/, stahl /ʃtʰa:l/ ?  I thought it was only under stress and even then that /ʃ/ in sp- and st- blocked it, I'm not sure about sk-.

Comment: @petitrien: Das Wort *»Mut«* ist eines der Wörter, die vor 1876 noch mit th geschrieben wurden. Es gib nach wie vor viele Menschen, die den Familiennamen *»Muth«* tragen: [Beispiel 1](http://www.mahringer-muth.at), [Beispiel 2](https://e5ayurveda.com/romana-muth-1), [Beispiel 3](https://www.wko.at/service/mitarbeiter.html?id=1423160), [Beispiel 4](http://www.katharina-muth.at) und in Wien gibt es die [Muthgasse](https://www.geschichtewiki.wien.gv.at/Muthgasse).

Comment: @petitrien: In historischen Schriften findet man auch das Wort Mutter in der Schreibweise *»Mutther«*: [Buch aus dem Jahr 1841](https://books.google.at/books?id=AW4AAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=%22mutther%22+-her&source=bl&ots=Zqddm7abOp&sig=ACfU3U3Jq4Fk9x5txCwVCUlQa1zMwSqQvA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ8KqpgNzjAhWKLlAKHVz8CqA4ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=%22mutther%22%20-her&f=false) und im englischen Sprachraum hat sich *»Mutther«* auch als Nachname erhalten. Außerdem kommt *»Mutther«* auch der schriftlichen Wiedergabe von Plattdeutschen Texten vor.

Comment: I guess the question I'm asking myself is whether the digraph "th" is the sign of an aspirated pronunciation of /t/.  But I'm not really familiar with the history of German spelling.

Comment: @petitrien: Wenn man aufmerksam zuhört, kann man bei beiden Wörtern (*»Mut«, »Mutter«*) auch das leise *h* nach dem *t* gut hören. Bei *st* (»**St**ahl«), *sp* (»**Sp**aß«), *sk* (»**Sk**elett«) bin ich mir in der Tat unsicher ob auch hier der Plosiv-Laut aspiriert wird. Ganz sicher nicht der Fall ist das bei *ts* (»rech**ts**«), *ps* (»Schna**ps**«) und *ks* (»lin**ks**«)

Comment: Würde sowas wie *Khönig* zählen? Von [1585](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/9356).

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage: Ja, klar

Comment: Ist das h wirklich dazu da, um die Aspiration anzuzeigen? Ich denke, mitunter spiegelt es einfach die Etymologie wieder, so im Falle von _Thür_ (gr. _thýra_ [θύρα]), ebenso _Thor_, _Thal_ (gr. _thólos_ [θόλος])  wo das _th_ das griechische Theta ersetzt.

Comment: Ich würde eher nach "ch" suchen, etwa *Krach* vs *krakelen* ~ *krakehlen*; *Chroma*, *Christ*, ergo *Chreutz*? *Krieg* oder *Krug* sind soweit dunkler Herkunft. \*k und \*kh wurden regelmäßig zu germanisch \*h, aber auch in Chlustern? Genauer habe ich mich damit oder mit \*g, \*gh nicht außeinandergesetzt; Immerhin wird Germanisch \*k- durchaus rekonstruiert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die bis Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts normativ gültigen Schreibweisen von Wörtern wie *Thron*, *Thal*, oder auch *Thaler* (Währung) mit /th/ im Anlaut, in Endungen wie bei *Muth*, oder in der Wortmitte wie bei *Unterthan* - bei letzterem von der Verbwurzel *thun*, sind meines Wissens ethymologischen und (leider) nicht phonetischen Ursprungs. Dies erklärt das Fehlen solcher altert(h)ümlicher Schreibweisen bei den anderen stimmlosen Plosiven wie /k/ und /p/.

Sie hatten möglicherweise vor langer Zeit einmal eine phonologische Basis, obwohl in anderen germanischen Sprachen wie Englisch und Dänisch erhalten gebliebene Lispellaute "bei uns" schon zu mittelhochdeutscher Zeit nicht mehr nachweisbar sind. Das heisst, zum etwas späteren Zeitpunkt erster Ansätze einer Normierung der hochdeutschen Schriftsprache (Gutenberg, Luther, gemeinhin der Beginn des Neuhochdeutschen) kann man davon ausgehen, dass der Kontrast /t/ - /th/ redundant war. Die derzeit weit verbreiteten Unregelmässigkeiten in der Orthografie scheinen mir unwahrscheinlicher, wenn ein phonetischer Kontrast vorliegt - hierfür habe ich aber offen gestanden keinerlei Belege.

Es kamen dann etwa zur Barockzeit zwei Dinge zusammen; (1) einen Hang zur Verschnörkelung auch der Schreibweise, was sich manchen - besonders vor 1919 adligen - Familiennamen erhalten hat (*Benckendorff*, wo es ein *Benkendorf* auch getan hätte), aber auch (2) der Beginn erster Systematisierung neusprachlicher Grammatik, wobei im zersplitterten deutschen Sprachraum durch das Fehlen einer starken politisch-kulturellen Zentralgewalt - anders als in Frankreich, Spanien, oder England - Latein und Griechisch stärker normbildend blieben. Es würde mich nicht überraschen, wenn sich *Thron, Unterthan* und dergleichen - ich wähle hier bewusst etwas wilhelminisch klingende Bespiele - bis weit ins industrielle Zeit(h)alter als barocke Restbestände mit redundantem Zierat(h) gehalten hätten.

Die unmarkierte Aspiration initialer, allein stehender Plosive wie /k/, /p/ und /t/ ist hingegen typisch für viele germanische Sprachen; sie entfällt allerdings, wenn diese Laute in bestimmten initialen Konsonantenclustern vorkommen. Das ist im Englischen und Niederländischen genauso.

Vergleiche:

- Engl. *pin*, *kin* und *tin*; aspiriert (man eine Kerze ausblasen), mit...
- Engl. *spin*, *skin* und *stink* (letzteres kein Minimalpaar); unaspiriert.

Solche (Fast-)Minimalpaare zu finden ist im Deutschen schwieriger, aber in  Wortkombinationen wie *kein Stein* ist das isoliert-initiale /k/ i.d.R. aspiriert, das /t/ im Digraph St- hingegen nicht - oder hörbar schwächer.

Das Sprachverständnis der meisten germanischen Sprach(norm)varianten verlässt sich in der Tat sehr stark auf die Aspiration zur Kennzeichnung der Stimmlosigkeit der Initiallaute /k/, /p/ und /t/. Für Englischsprecher klingen die Worte *pin* und *tin* (Stecknadel bzw. Dose / "Zinn") unaspiriert gesprochen, etwa durch Spanisch- oder Italienischsprecher, wie *bin* und *din* (Tonne/(Müll)Eimer bzw. Dröhnen).

Genauso klingt im Niederländischen *tuin* (Garten) unaspiriert wie *duin* (Düne).

Sprecher eines chemisch gereinigten Hochdeutsch karikieren aus exakt diesem Grund manche (mittel)deutsche Dialekte, die exakt diese Aspiration aufweichen. Das vermeintlich sächsische *Gofferraum* ist so ein Beispiel. Bei genauem Hinhören merkt man, dass dieses Wort selbst stark dialektgefärbt tatsächlich niemals mit /g/ gesprochen wird, sondern dass einfach der gewohnte Aspirationsmarker fehlt.

Leider sind Aussprachemuster wie aspirierte Plosive dermassen integraler T(h)eil der deutschen Phonologie, dass sie nicht markiert werden. Das /ph/ als /f/ ist anderen (griechischen) Ursprungs, da es Grund zur Annahme gibt, dass der Buchstabe *phi* zu klassischer Zeit tatsächlich als *bilabialer* statt *labiodentaler* Reibelaut realisiert wurde. Bei der im Deutschen stark inkonsistenten Übernahme griechischer Wörter wie *Fonologie* und *Fonetik* (haha, versus *Photographie*... das soll einer verstehen! :-) wurde hierbei etwas schnöselig hyperkorrigiert, da es den phonemischen Kontrast zwischen *bilabialer* und *labiodentaler* Aussprache nicht gibt. Genau wie ein gelispeltes /th/ wird ein bilabiales /f/ schlimmstenfalls als Sprachstörung, in jedem Fall als Normabweichung wahrgenommen.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Was man zur Geschichte der Aspiration noch anfügen kann, ist, dass im Oberdeutschen ursprüngliche keine Aspiration bei T und P vorkam, da ja die ursprünglichen germanischen aspirierten [pʰ] und [tʰ] zu Z und PF verschoben wurden. K hingegen wurde in vielen Gebieten nicht verschoben und blieb aspiriert. Die fehlende Aspiration macht verständlich, warum man jahrhundertelang schwankte zwischen «deutsch» und «teutsch» usw., wo doch heute durch die Aspiration ein sehr deutlicher Unterschied besteht. Die Aspiration begann sich erst unter wachsendem norddeutschen Einfluss durchzusetzen.

Comment: Excellente Antwort!

Comment: man kann auch einfach eine deutsch akzentuierte Aussprache der englischen Begriffe oder anderes heranziehen wenn sich sonst kein Minimalpaar findet. "(er) skandiert, kandiert", wäre aber immerhin schonmal eins. "Skat" [ska:t] vs "Qat" [kat] passt leider nicht ganz, ist nur erwähnenswert da das arabische auch "Khat, Kath, Kat" transcribiert wird. Auf elu.se und andernorts las ich die Tage grade erst, dass etwa die Schreibweise "school" eher klassizistisch motiviert sei, nicht baroque, und also an Latein und Griechisch angelehnt. Zwar zeigt "Schule" gar keinen Plosiv, aber doch ein *H*.

Answer (score 1):

Im Deutschen werden p, t und k generell am Wortende und vor Vokal aspiriert. Am Wortende entfällt die Aspiration manchmal durch die Verbindung mit einem nachfolgendem Wort - Bei "er ist krank gewesen" wird das auslautende k nicht aspiriert. Aber auch bei "Er ist krank zu Hause" oder "Er ist krank und kann nicht kommen" findet oft keine Aspiration statt (könnte regional unterschiedlich sein.)

Bei allen Sp- und St-Anlauten gibt.
Aber auch bei vorausgehendem s oder f kommt es normalerweise nicht zu Aspiration:

Feste werden nicht Festhe gesprochen, Haftung nicht Hafthung.

Bei nachfolgendem Konsonanten ist die Aussprache nach meiner Wahrnehmung nicht einheitlich, hier gibt es oft keine oder eine sehr schwache Aspiration, man hört z. T. aber auch aspirierte Aussprachen z. B. für Trommel, Trage. Dagegen kann ich mir "prächtig" nicht aspiriert vorstellen. "Krumm" oder "klein" können etwas aspiriert sein.